# What defences did Camp David have circa 2017

Tags: government, military, earth, military-defense

The aliens whose kids sent Jormungandr, the Snakebot of Doom, have shown up at Earth, and have announced that they will be taking over administration of Earth for the foreseeable future.  As part of the transition of power, the alien leaders will be visiting Earth's leaders.

Given that Washington DC was destroyed during Jormungandr's attack, the US President is working from Camp David.

As the alien leaders are coming to visit, with or without the permission of the President, Camp David's defences will be put to the test.  In effect, I am planning a fictional 'Battle of Camp David', but in order to do that,  I need a realistic idea of the defences.

However, all I can find out about those defences is that it is defended by "Marine Security Company, Camp David".  Details of MSC-CD are very thin on the internet, and I haven't been able to find  their table of organization and equipment.

So, my question is: What defenders did Camp David have circa 2017?  How many marines are present, and what weapons do they have, including personal arms, vehicles and emplaced weapons?

I understand that this information may not be available, and if anyone reading this question knows, that they may not be permitted to reveal the details for ongoing security reasons.

For that reason, I am prepared to accept answers that present a reasonable, educated guess.

Comment: 2017 is pretty recent history. And the US Marines have access to basically the same kind of weaponry as the rest of USMIL. It's not like they've got magic laser weapons that are only set up at at Camp David. If some radical kind of weapon _was_ invented in the last 5 years, the public wouldn't know about it, and Camp David would not be the most likely place for those weapons to be deployed.

Comment: @Tom, Let's not speculate about experimental weapons without good reason.  All I need is the numbers of troops and the equipment they might reasonably have, given that the President is on-site.

Comment: "This touches on our Real World Question debate. Real World questions are permitted only if there is a dependency on your worldbuilding. As a specific example, a question about Real World history is only permissible when used as an example when building an alternative history or the history of a fictional world. (Source: [Help Center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))" please see this [meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8491/a-concise-list-of-the-rules).

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane I am planning for a fictional 'Battle of Camp David', in case I hadn't made that clear in the question.  That requires knowledge of the defences, or in the absence of real-world data, an educated guess.  I do not have either right now.

Comment: The problem with any "real world" answer is that they would be based on information at one point in time. If the actual seat of government had moved from DC to Camp David because of an attack, we can be assured that the defenses of that time would have been redesigned and greatly improved upon. It is more likely that the president would be in a more secure location than Camp David anyway. (There are bunkers intended to survive a nuke hit available to be used.)

Comment: Camp David, AKA [Naval Support Facility Thurmont](http://www.militarybases.us/navy/naval-support-facility-thurmont/), would likely have the same defenses as the White House with the added benefits of being an actual military base. And I hate to say it, but this Q is the epitome of why [I dislike the current Real Life Questions policy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6410/40609). This has nothing to do with worldbuilding. The world was already built. It's just storybuilding research. (Sorry to use your Q as a soapbox, Monty.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it only asks for information about the real world.

Comment: @Daron Real world questions are on topic here.

Comment: Given that there's no question in my mind that the real answer is classified, what are the criteria for which is the best guess?  If I guess as part of an answer that they would have 6 of air defence system A and someone else guesses 10 of air defence system B, how can the best answer be judged?  Any answer sufficiently detailed to justify choices would be the length of a long book covering all conceivable contingencies and still may not have a "best" answer.

Comment: You might want to read up on the Wolfschanze - It was used during a hot war, so not really comparable to Camp David today, but in your scenario there is quite a bit more tension than today, as i gather? It's defences are minutely detailed